# nx webpack css-loader issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, nomachine-nx

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const sass = require('sass');

module.exports = (config, context) => {
    return merge(config, {
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.sass$/i,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                modules: {
                                    localIdentName: '[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                implementation: sass
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    });
};
```

[image]

freshly generated nx workspace with react project in it.
trying to make a custom webpack.config to generate the hashes via sass files

but there is a lot of errors falling down.

Also i tried configure the babel. Added the plugin babel-plugin-react-css-modules and that's doesn't help

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, having a very similar problem!

Answer (score 0):

NX has it's own style-loader which is part of the config which You are merging.

To resolve this, You will have to remove that loader from NX config. I did it manually by looping through all of the `module.rules` and ignoring whichever I don't want. So to fix Your issue, You would do it this way:

```
module.exports = (config, context) => {
  const conf = merge(config, {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.sass$/i,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                modules: {
                  localIdentName: '[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                }
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                implementation: sass
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  });

  // Remove unwanted NX rules
  const mods = [];
  conf.module.rules.forEach((rule) => {
    if (rule.test != '/\\.css$|\\.scss$|\\.sass$|\\.less$|\\.styl$/') {
      mods.push(rule);
    }
  });
  conf.module.rules = mods;

  return conf;
};
```

This took me a long time to figure out. Your CSS rule might be different, depending on Your NX version. Just `console.log(rule.test)` to check what is the rule which You want to ignore.